# How do I set the color for a Vscrollbar in flash builder 4.7?

Tags: flash-builder

I want to set a custom color to a Vscrollbar in adobe flash builder 4.7. If anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<s:VScrollBar chromeColor="#0000FF" height="50%"/>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by further explanation, just in case it is not understood by those unfamiliar with the technology. Code only answers are not rated the best in Stack Overflow.